# See what queries are cached in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any way to view the queries currently in cache in BigQuery? Or is it safe to assume that *all* queries made within a certain timeframe will be cached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [Job metadata](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs) to query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_*` and obtain a detailed list with information about all the running jobs and the past ones (up to 180 days). The field you are looking for is the boolean `cache_hit`. With the following query, you will retrieve a list of all the cached jobs together with additional fields.

```
SELECT
  creation_time,
  user_email,
  job_id,
  cache_hit,
  total_bytes_processed
FROM
  `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
WHERE
  job_type = "QUERY"
  AND cache_hit = TRUE
ORDER BY
  creation_time DESC
```

Notice that the above query displays results for the US region and there are [other available fields](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs#schema) that can provide you interesting information. Additionally, you can make use of the [`bq query`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_query) command to run this query in the command line.

```
bq query --nouse_legacy_sql \
'SELECT
 creation_time, user_email, job_id, cache_hit, total_bytes_processed
FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
WHERE job_type = "QUERY" AND cache_hit = TRUE'
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. Thanks @Juan Fernández Afonso!